# Toggle audio in speaker to ear-speaker and ear-speaker to speaker

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We are using third party Audio/Video SDK in our Xamarin.Forms.Android project. Now problem is that by default audio comes in speaker mode, instead of ear-speaker. I was tried to search solution in internet and found below code to set audio in ear-speaker and speaker. After implement below code audio off in speaker but not able to listen via ear-speaker, if I set SpeakerphoneOn=true then I can listen via Speakerphone but if I set SpeakerphoneOn=false then I can't list via ear-speaker.

Additional point, Mode value is always comes "InCommunication" even after change to InCall or any other mode.

I have set below permission too in my Xamarin project.
Permission:

```
var audioManager = (Android.Media.AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AudioService);

audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = !audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn;
```

Comment: It is working now. Given above solution is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check when mode is ear-speaker , the volume value whether is 0 .The volume of their two modes is controlled separately.

```
var audioManager = (Android.Media.AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AudioService);
audioManager.Mode = Mode.InCommunication;
audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = false;
audioManager.SetStreamVolume(Stream.Music, audioManager.GetStreamMaxVolume(Stream.Music), VolumeNotificationFlags.ShowUi);
```

Comment: I tried it but problem is not solved, Still I can't hear in my earspeker

Comment: @JohnSmith  Glad be helpful : )